# ASP.net MVC, calling a view from different Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an `EmployeeController` and `ShiftController`. In the `Index` View of `EmployeeController` I show `EmployeeDetails` with options of `Edit`, `Delete` and `GetShifts` (this gets all the shifts of that employee - EmpShifts.aspx).
In EmpShifts.aspx, I want to give a link to `Create New Shift`. I want to know how to call `Create` View of Shifts from `EmpShifts.aspx`.

Am I having the wrong design structure. Suggestions on that are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When generating links you can specify the action and controller they are pointing to:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Create new shift", "create", "shift") %>
```

Same for HTML forms allowing you to POST:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("create", "shift")) <% { %>
    ...
<% } %>
```

Your design is correct. It is perfectly normal for having links/forms in some view pointing to other controller actions.

Comment: Thank You for such a quick reply. It works like wonder.
I want to know; it is possible also pass data from one view to another.
Like if I want to pass `EmployeeID` from `EmpShifts.aspx` to `CreateNewShift`

Comment: @Vabs, yes it is possible. You could use the routeValues parametrer when generating those links. For example: `<%= Html.ActionLink("Create new shift", "create", "shift", new { EmployeeID = "123" }, null) %>`.